# Flaky tests are not taken into account by the Publish Test Results Task

Tags: azure-devops

We have enabled support for flaky test on DevOps and configured it to succeed if there are only flaky tests failing.

[image]

What we observe however is that the job still fails if we use the Publish Test Results task with failTaskOnFailedTests:true

[image]

Reading the docs this task should take into account the flaky status of the test and the job should succeed. But it still marks the task as failed if only flaky tests are failing.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/flaky-test-management?view=azure-devops#flaky-test-management-and-reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same issue. I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6104) and will keep track on it. You can also follow up on that thread.

You can also report this issue on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).